# Why does casting an enum stored in an object to an int return a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I have a property of type `object`, which contains an `Enum` value, and when I cast it using `(int)value`, it returns a `string` of the Enum's name. Why?

The code where I noticed this is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110464/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-int-to-enum-converter/7110658#7110658). Using `Convert.ToInt32()` correctly casts the `Enum` to an `int`, but I was just curious why I would get a string back when using `(int)`. It doesn't even throw me an error.

**Edit**

Here's a quick sample. I commented where I put the breakpoint, and was using the immediate window to determine what the output was.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Int32 SomeNumber { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SomeNumber = 1;
        RootWindow.DataContext = this;

    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3
}


/// <summary>
/// Returns true if the int value equals the Enum parameter, otherwise returns false
/// </summary>
public class IsIntEqualEnumParameterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null || value == null) return false;

        if (parameter.GetType().IsEnum && value is int)
        {
            // Breakpoint here
            return (int)parameter == (int)value;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="RootWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IsIntEqualEnumParameterConverter x:Key="IsIntEqualEnumParameterConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeNumber, Converter={StaticResource IsIntEqualEnumParameterConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MyEnum.Value1}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Edit #2**

Just hoping to clear up some confusion...

I said it was returning a string because running `?((int)parameter)` in the Immediate Window was returning the enum name, while running `?System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter)` was correctly displaying the int.

I found afterwards that it was actually evaluating correctly to the DataTrigger all along. I thought it wasn't because my control wasn't visible at runtime, however I discovered that was because of an error in my XAML (I forgot a `Grid.Column` property, so one control was overlapping another).

Sorry for the confusing question.

**Edit #3**

Here's some console app code demonstrating the situation just for Jon :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object value;
        value = Test.Value1;

        // Put breakpoint here
        // Run ?(int)value vs Convert.ToInt32(value) in the immediate window
        // Why does the first return Value1 while the 2nd returns 1?
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public enum Test
{ 
    Value1 = 1
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a working example of the code?

Comment: Are you putting it into a string? Are you casting it in a Console.WriteLine()? I'm not seeing the same issue.  Casting it to an int seems to give me the expected behavior.

Comment: Something else is going on. `object o = MyEnum.Blah; int i = (int)o;` sets `i` to the integer value of the enumeration member.

Comment: That ain't possible.  You can't direct cast and get something of a different type.

Comment: Yep, add a snippet of code showing the source for "parameter" so we can better evaluate what is going on.  It's probably something fairly straightforward, but without an example of the call, we cannot see.

Comment: @Leslie Sure, code added. It's a WPF Converter

Comment: The behavior was noticed by putting a breakpoint there and running `(int)parameter` in the immediate window

Comment: @Rachel: we see the code of your converter, but need to see the call to that code itself if possible.

Comment: @Rachel That will just show the value of the expression in text form; the expression itself isn't a string, though.

Comment: If that were to evaluate to a string, how would the cast even work? You'd get an InvalidCastException, no?

Comment: Do you mean if you check `parameter is int` at the immediate window it will return `false` then?

Comment: @Rachel: BTW, to your other point, Convert.ToInt32() will work on a string representation of an enum because string and enum both implement IConvertible and it's a conversion, not a cast.  (int) is a cast (when performed from object) not a conversion, so if the object is not an int, you should throw an InvalidCastException.

Comment: Please paste a copy of what you're seeing in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code that's giving you this problem? Once you cast to int, it will stay int, so I suspect something else is going on here. (Most likely, the type of the variable you're displaying is an Enum. When you display an Enum via ToString() or similar if the variable holds a defined value from the enumeration the name is displayed instead of the numeric value.)

Comment: I've just tried Rachel's console code, and got the same result. Interestingly, if you change the type of `value` to `Test`, it shows 1 instead...

Comment: @Jon I noticed that too... no clue why. Perhaps it's just a VS bug.

Comment: @Rachel: Sounds like it. I suggest you report it on connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're being duped by the Immediate Window. It's not clear exactly what you *did* in the Immediate Window, but I can say with *absolute* certainty that if you cast to an `int` you do *not* get a `string` back. The type system *completely* prevents that from happening.

Comment: You are correct, the value is correct in the output, just not in the immediate window. Good to know that I shouldn't blindly trust the immediate window. (I had an error in my XAML which was making me think the converter was always returning false since a control was not visible)

Comment: And I was writing `?((int)parameter)` in the Immediate window and it was returning `Value1`. Running `?System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter)` was correctly returning `1`

Comment: @Rachel: Hmm... can't even reproduce that. But I very rarely use the Immediate Window to start with :)

Comment: Strange, I double-checked by pulling out the relevant code and putting it in its own application, and the same thing occurs. I posted the code I used in my sample if you want to try. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate, SP1, AsyncCTP Refresh, and no mods.

Comment: @Rachel: I'll give it a try later on. If you see it in a console app as well, it could be even simpler :) If I can reproduce it more simply, I'll post that code here.

Comment: Sure, I did a quick check and it does the same thing with a console app. Added a trimmed down version of the code to the question. I'd love to know why it's returning the enum name instead of the int value.

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks - it makes a *huge* difference to me to be able to do everything in just one file, nothing in the designer, nothing messy...

Answer (score 1):

It's technically impossible what you describe here. What you see is the NAME of enumeration member which is shown by debugger. Think of this like kind of "syntax sugare". So the real problem IMHO, is that just to ints are not equal.

To check this:

Read your "string", Check integer assigned to in enumeration declared, and ceck if  integer actually equals to that one you get like a parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really "why" and not "how", I realize that.

However, here's how:

```
enum Options : int { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3 }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    object _Option = Options.three;

    // shows "three"
    MyTextBox.Text = ((Options)_Option).ToString();

    // shows "3"
    MyTextBox.Text = ((int)((Options)_Option)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run this code sample into oblivion, and I'm finding it to return false each time because the `value is int` is failing. value is an object, not an integer.

Comment: The runtime value of `parameter` is an Enum

Comment: Yes. I corrected my statement.  That's what you get when you copy/paste.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine what is happening is that your `object parameter` is coming in as a `string` value and thus your call to

```
 if (parameter.GetType().IsEnum && value is int)
```

is false and you skip the body and `return false` directly.

Instead, use Enum.Parse() or Convert.ToInt32() to change the string into either the enum value or the int value and then compare.

Comment: Nope, both properties in that statement evaluate to true

Comment: No worries, was a guess based on the data at the time.