# Using enum value in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I have defined an enum in C#

```
public enum PointerStyle
{
  Pointer,
  Block,
  Slider
} ;
```

I am using it as a dependency property on a WPF custom control

```
public static DependencyProperty DisplayStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayStyle", typeof(PointerStyle), typeof(Pointer), new PropertyMetadata(PointerStyle.Pointer));

public PointerStyle DisplayStyle
{
  get { return (PointerStyle)GetValue(DisplayStyleProperty); }
  set { SetValue(DisplayStyleProperty, value); }
}
```

and using it in a ControlTemplate

```
<Trigger Property="DisplayStyle" Value="{x:Static local:PointerStyle.Block}">
```

Very often, but not always, the editor underlines most of the code and shows the error "'Block' is not a valid value for property 'DisplayStype'." as shown in the following screen shot

[image]

This is in Visual Studio 2015.

At runtime, the code works perfectly.
In the design window of my test program, the control is rendered totally incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the best way to refer to an enum value in XAML?

(I would be happy to use a TypeConverter and to define the value as a string, but I can't find a good example of how do it.)

Comment: Did you try to simply write `Value="Block"` in the Trigger? Type conversion from string to enum usually works out of the box in XAML.

Comment: I believe you are using it correctly, but you can see Enum Converter example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279602/how-can-i-use-enum-types-in-xaml

Comment: @RicardoSerra That answer shows a binding value converter, which should not be confused with a type converter. However, no binding is involved here.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. Simply writing Value="Block" works and my control is rendered correctly in the design window. I had presumed that I need to define my own TypeConverter to get this functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF already provides built-in type conversion from string to enum types.

So you could simply write

```
<Trigger Value="Block" ...>
```

Comment: If you rename the enum value, this will break :(

Comment: My point is it would be great to have an equivalent to nameof(). Using string is dangerous.

Comment: Maybe, but tell that Microsoft, not us. We can't do much about that.